# Sub list element's top space trailing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple list elements they change by hiding(display:none) but even hidden elements takes space from top.

Try clicking sub menu items you will see. Don't mind blank images.

http://fantasycore.com/clients/menu/menu.html

I don't have inline element inside, checked all. They are also absolute. How can they take space?

[image]

Comment: I see the huge white space in the place where the menu was is being held by left: 460px; in your CSS menu.css line 312

Comment: That is not the problem. The space from top. And i use stylus. That is not a good reason to give negative point.

Comment: What top space? Please place here some screenshot with whitespace highlighted.

Comment: It's not because something is taking space. It's because the submenu position is inherited(I'm not sure it's the right word) from menu item, therefore the lower ones will be shown lower down.

Comment: @emrah I gave you downvote for beeing offensive - i only asked you for screenshot. Whay did you gave me downvote for ALL my questions without reading them is now question for the administrators team. Have a nice day.

Comment: Don't vandalize your posts. These can be helpful for other users.

Comment: @Tushar stackoverflow doesn't play nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @FaridNouriNeshat mentioned in the comments, the issue with your approach is that `position:absolute;` is absolutely positioned to the nearest parent that is not `position: static;`, which in this case, is the immediate li parent.  See below for a quick example:

```js
$('.main-wrapper > ul > li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
```

```css
.main-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 50%;
}
li {
  padding: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
li:first-child {
  border: none;
}
ul ul {
  display: none;
}

li.active ul {
  display: block;
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <ul>
  <li>
    Menu 1
    <ul>
      <li>Submenu 1a</li>
      <li>Submenu 1b</li>
      <li>Submenu 1c</li>
      <li>Submenu 1d</li>
      <li>Submenu 1e</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu 2
    <ul>
      <li>Submenu 2a</li>
      <li>Submenu 2b</li>
      <li>Submenu 2c</li>
      <li>Submenu 2d</li>
      <li>Submenu 2e</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu 3
    <ul>
      <li>Submenu 3a</li>
      <li>Submenu 3b</li>
      <li>Submenu 3c</li>
      <li>Submenu 3d</li>
      <li>Submenu 3e</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    Menu 4
    <ul>
      <li>Submenu 4a</li>
      <li>Submenu 4b</li>
      <li>Submenu 4c</li>
      <li>Submenu 4d</li>
      <li>Submenu 4e</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: I understood. Nearest element was pos:rel. Thanks. Should i change the question.

Comment: Yes, make sure the question is clear for future users looking at it!  The screenshot was helpful too.

Comment: Edited the image for future comings. Link will be dead probably. 
I don't know how to change question. I am not native so. I still can't describe it.

Comment: Adding a code sample in the question (a snippet like I used) can help communicate your issue also